# Unable to copy files from azure file share to local disk in azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-file-copy

I am having azure VM, where I have mounted Azure File share as drive(V:), I am trying to create azure pipeline which will do a copy task to copy files from mounted Azure File share(v:) to local disk (D:).

In release pipeline I chose Copy task and I had given the source as Azure file share drive path (\\filesharepath\foldername)  and destination as (D:\Foldername) but when I run the pipe line am getting the error

> Unhandled: Not found sourcefolder: (\\filesharepath\foldername)

I also tried other way to create a PowerShell script task and created a powershell script (inside the azure VM) with Copy-Item command to do copy task but while running the pipeline got error

> `Copy-Item: cannot find drive. The drive does not exists`.

while in the azure VM, I am able to run the powershell script and file copy does is happening, the issue occur only when I run the scripts through pipeline, how to overcome these issues?

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: I am doing these task in release pipeline and there are 2 VM in deployment group. should I need to configure powershell script task under Agent job? @VitoLiu-MSFT

Comment: Since you could run power shell script to copy the file, we could also configure powershell script task under agent job to copy the file.